# How to get appWidgetId in AppWidgetProvider?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I need to get the specific appWidgetId in AppWidgetProvider, not a bundle of appWidgetIds[] but the specific id which user clicked.

I could get it in its configure activity, using the "intent.getExtra().getInt(AppWidgetManager.APP_WIDGET_ID)" says like 504.

But it is so different in AppWidgetProvider, I will be appreciate it if anyone give me a hand.thanks in advance.

```
public class WidgetBox extends AppWidgetProvider implements Widget {

private int _widgetId = ?; // not appWidgetIds[]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get an array of Ids when the widget life cycle methods are called.
You can simply iterate through the provided Ids like this:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, final int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int n = appWidgetIds.length;
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        final int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        // some logic here
    }
}
```

if you need to invoke some action, this is done using a pending intent during configuration (or a later update):

```
final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
final Intent defineIntent = new Intent(context, YourTargetActivity.class);
defineIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0 /* no request code */, defineIntent, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.view_id, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: What is this appWidgetIDs? Why is it a series? And why we do same process for all elements of appWidgetIds?

Comment: The user may deploy the same widget multiple times (possibly with different configurations, e.g. sunset at different locations). The API provides onUpdate() with an array of the IDs of all the widgets.